# Salesforce CPQ for Multi Year Product- Add Segment Dynamically in Quote Line Editor(add segment Year 0 or Year 1 Or Year 2 Dynamically)

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

We have one of our old functionality in CPQ -
Whenever a picklist value is changed Year 0 column is automatically gets added to our MDQ product, but we have no clue how it is getting added.

Checked below already but no luck -
QCP
Triggers

Our Requirement is to add Segment Dynamically for Multi Year Product without click on Custom and then add Segment Year 1 -- Start Date -- End Date

Checked below already but no luck -
QCP
Triggers

Our Requirement is to add Segment Dynamically for Multi Year Product without click on Custom and then add Segment Year 1 -- Start Date -- End Date